# Return rows if and only if all the values specified in the IN clause are present

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table called `users` that have `id` and `name` columns. Let's suppose I have users with following ids:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I need to craft a query that returns rows if and only if all the values specified inside IN clause are present in the table, for instance:

```
select * from users where id in (1, 5, 7)
```

should return 3 rows, whereas

```
select * from users where id in (0, 1, 9)
```

shouldn't return any row despite 1 being a valid id.

How can I craft a query that returns rows only when the values inside `IN` clause are all valid?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from users
    where id in (0, 1, 9)
      AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
                    where id in (0, 1, 9) )
               = 3;    -- where "3" is the number of distinct items in IN
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for `id in (0, 1, 9)` if the `users` table had `ids (0, 1, 9, 12)` in it. But such a case is valid in OP's question and should return 3 rows. Actually, I think this would also return 2 rows incorrectly in the case of the table having only `(1, 9, 12)` as rows in it too.

Comment: @J.D. -- Thanks.  I fixed it.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense now, lol.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions for this, and turn it into a join on a `VALUES` constructor (or a table).

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT u.*,
      COUNT(u.id) OVER () AS userCount
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          COUNT(*) OVER () AS idCount
        FROM (VALUES
          ROW(1),
          ROW(5),
          ROW(7)
        ) v(id)
    ) v
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = v.id
) u
WHERE u.userCount = u.idCount;
```

If you know the number of rows in the `VALUES` you can simplify

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT u.*,
      COUNT(u.id) OVER () AS userCount
    FROM (VALUES
          ROW(1),
          ROW(5),
          ROW(7)
    ) v(id)
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = v.id
) u
WHERE u.userCount = 3;
```